# 1053 windows service did not respond in timely fashion

Tags: c#, windows, service

I have one Web app running in IIS and communicates to a Windows Service through WCF hosted in the same machine. Internally Windows Service executes various job and sometimes it is quite busy with processing User requests. At 1st I had the issue with Start of Service because it some imes take much time to Start & eventually throws the Error i.e. Service Timeout. To fix this I moved the code to another Thread instead of the Main Thread. Everything works fine but now I observed that some times I am getting the error on Service Stop i.e.

```
**1053 windows service did not respond in timely fashion**
```

My Service OnStop() code:

```
protected override void OnStop()
        {
            // Stop the WCF service
            if (myServiceHost != null)
            {
                myServiceHost.Close();
                myServiceHost = null;
            }

            // Stop the scheduler

            if (myScheduleManager != null)
            {
                myScheduleManager.Stop();
            }

            // Update the registry value
            Logger.GetInstance().LogEvent(this.GetType().Name, LogLevel.INFO, "Updating registry...");
            Settings.GetInstance().LastStopTime = DateTime.Now.ToString();

            Logger.GetInstance().LogEvent(this.GetType().Name, LogLevel.INFO, "Service stopped.");
        }
```

It generally happens when Service is too busy. But finally it stops after 30-40 mins of time. I know this happens due to Time out issue in Windows Service coz the default time is very less & it treats it as Time out.

My question what is the best practice to avoid such bottle necks means shall I move my Stop related tasks under another Thread & do asynchronous call to release resources in that Thread. But what will happen if during release resources, User will Start the Service?

Comment: myScheduleManager is the Quartz JobScheduler which schedules various long running jobs on Service Start.While during Stopping calling myScheduleManager.Stop() calls Quartz's Shutdown method i.e myQuartzScheduler.Shutdown(true) Quartz waits for all the job to finish, thats why it takes much time to finish.I can't make myQuartzScheduler.Shutdown(false) coz it will put my jobs in an unstable state. I can separate this to another async method from OnStop() of Service & can use the Cancellation Pattern but what happen if user will again Start the Service while it is finishing the job in background?

Comment: in this case, is that an option that you can know the service is stopping and you shouldn't continue to start until job is finished in the background ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just guessing, but perhaps it will help to track down the problem:

You have this `myScheduleManager.Stop()` which, (i guess) waits for processes to be finished.
This is nice, but Windows only gives you 30 Seconds to execute `ServiceBase.OnStop()`.

If you are doing asynchronous processing here, you could perhaps implement the CancellationPattern by using the CancellationTokens from the .NET-Framework.

Answer (score 2):

Just a guess but it might help: make sure you set your solution configuration to Release rather than Debug.

Answer (score 1):

The easy approach probably you can identify to build a boolean type `IsRunning` in your `myScheduleManager` and determine during the OnStop()

```
if (myScheduleManager.IsRunning)
    myScheduleManager.Stop();
```

however, you have different threads finishing the processes which could over 30 seconds but you also can do abort your processes by applying

```
if (myScheduleManager.IsRunning && !_workerThread.Join(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30))
    _workerThread.Abort 

myScheduleManager.Stop();
```

However, I didn't see the full code snippets so that's my guess to your scenario.